# jQuery Mobile open dialog multiple times call function multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

i have problem with jquery mobile. The function in the dialog run multiple times. I open a dialog with

```
   $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "./comments.html", {
            role: "dialog"
        });
```

After that i close the dialog and open it again. When i use the submit function in this dialog the function called mutliple times (same count opened dialog in this session).

How can i prevent this?

Thanks for help.

Follow code is in the comments.html

```
        $(document).on("vclick", "#submit", function() {
            console.log(String(localStorage.getItem("var1")));
           $.post("http://xxx/savecomment", {
                var1: String(localStorage.getItem("var1")),
                var2: String(localStorage.getItem("var2")),
                comment: String($('#text').val())
            }, function (responseREST) {
                                    console.log(responseREST);
               get_comments();

            });
        });
```

and i close the dialog with follow link

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete" href="#" data-rel="back">Close</a>
```

My solution is:

```
$(document).off('vclick', '#submit').on("vclick", "#submit", function() { });
```

Comment: Is the submit function in the comments.html page.?? If so try (one) instead of (on) click. (One) means run once. If not paste in the code you use including the Dialog page to have a look

Comment: It maybe the (vclick). That's causes trouble sometimes and fires other events. Cant you use a Normal (click) instead? or can you try ($("#submit").on("vclick" ... ) so the vclick is not binded to the whole document

Comment: i have the solution. I use this code.


    $(document).off('vclick', '#submit').on("vclick", "#submit", function() {

didnt know is the best solution.